# How to Set Two Transition Durations for Multiple CSS Transforms

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I would like the transform: translateY() transition and the transform: scale() transition to have a duration of 1.5 seconds and 0.5 seconds respectively. I can't seem to find a way to do this after multiple attempts and searches. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
//..CSS..//

.circle1 {
        z-index: 1056;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #BBBBBB;
        position: fixed;
        top: 150px; 
        margin: 0 auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Raleway-Light;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
        box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
       -webkit-transition:  1.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
        transform: translateY(2000px);
        cursor: pointer;
}

.circle1.open {
        transform: translateY(0px);
}

.circle1:hover {
        transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: did you tried `transition-duration: 1.5s;`?

Comment: Since both are changed using the same property (`transform`) I don't believe it's possible :/ Perhaps you can nest two element, translate the parent and scale the child?

Comment: Agree with @powerbuoy, you can use animation instead of transition and change class of your element on mouseover.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'll do that and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Check the snippet  below that i have post . i think its helpful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set different transition on **different property** of a element. Here, you've only one property, you can try to use **animation** instead of transition.

**Example**

```css
.mydiv{
  background-color:#ddd;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  transform:scale(1);
 }

.mydiv:hover{
  animation:transformanim 1.5s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes transformanim{
  0%{
    transform:scale(1) translateX(0px);
  }
   33%{
     transform:scale(1.33) translateX(20px); /*0.5s*/
  }
  100%{
    transform:scale(2) translateX(20px);; /*1.5s here*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Oops, accidentally gave it to the wrong person. This is a possible alternative although can get messy at times. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

> Use CSS  **transform:translateY(160px) scale(2.2)**

**see snippet below-**

```css
   

 .circle1 {
            z-index: 1056;
            width: 80px;
            height: 80px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: #BBBBBB;
            position: fixed;
            top:50px; 
            margin: 0 auto;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Raleway-Light;
            text-decoration: none;
            list-style-type: none;
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
           -webkit-transition:  1.5s ease-in-out;
            transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
            transform: translateY(50px);
            cursor: pointer;
    }


    .circle1:hover {
             transform:translateY(160px) scale(2.2);
    }
```

```html
<div class="circle1">
</div>
```